# Ambiguous Reference for type pthread_mutex_t

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5, pthreads

I have declared

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

in the global space of my main program, main.cpp.

However, whenever I try to refer to it in a function definition, for example,

```
void foo(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ...
}
```

the following error message will be displayed:

> reference to ‘mutex’ is ambiguous

Any idea what's going on? If it helps, this is being written in xcode, and I have included  in the header of the program.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out after I changed to name from mutex to mutex1, the errors disappeared. I guess because mutex is a function somewhere...

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with namespace pollution. Do you have any `using namespace` directives?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the name 'mutex' to some different name. Same happened with me, I was using 'lock' as name and it threw the same error.